# Strange EOFexception while do readObject() in deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, server, udp, deserialization

I am trying to process an object on the server with UDP. I serialize it, send it to the server. On the server, I deserialize, modify, then serialize back to send back to the client. On the client I get it, and when I try to readObject () I get an EOF exception. Please help, what could be the problem? I didn't find the answer anywhere.

This is client:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Help help = new Help("WTF");

        try {
            byte[] objByteArray = serialize(help);

            DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            int port = 6789;

            int objLength = objByteArray.length;

            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(objByteArray, objLength, host, port);
            ds.send(dp);


            dp = new DatagramPacket(objByteArray, objLength);
            ds.receive(dp);

            byte[] new_arr = objByteArray;


            Help deserializedObj = (Help) deserialize(objByteArray);

            System.out.println(deserializedObj.getData());

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)){

            oos.writeObject(obj);

            byte[] objByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
            return objByteArray;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static Object deserialize(byte[] arr) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Object result = null;
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(arr);
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais)){

            result = ois.readObject();

        }
        catch (IOException e){
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And this is Server:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String filepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\Server\\Data\\Collection.json";
        CollectionManager.setFilePath(filepath);

        byte[] arr = new byte[100000];

        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(6789);
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(arr, arr.length);
        ds.receive(dp);

        try {

            Help deserializedObj = (Help) deserialize(arr);

            deserializedObj.setData("Server finished work!");

            System.out.println("Done!");


            byte[] serializedObj = serialize(deserializedObj);

            InetAddress host = dp.getAddress();
            int port = dp.getPort();
            dp = new DatagramPacket(serializedObj, serializedObj.length, host, port);
            ds.send(dp);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)){

            oos.writeObject(obj);

            byte[] objByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
            return objByteArray;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static Object deserialize(byte[] arr) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Object result = null;
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(arr);
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais)){

            result = ois.readObject();

        }
        catch (IOException e){
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And also the classes:

```
public class Help extends Command implements Serializable {
    public Help(String name){
        super.setName(name);
    }

    private String data;

    public void setData(String s){
        data = s;
    }

    public String getData(){
        return data;
    }


    @Override
    public void execute() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing strange about it. You are assuming that the reply is as long as the result of serializing `new Help("WTF")`. Why? It isn't.

Comment: Why? I am trying to reply with the length of a new object, not old. How can i know a new object size?

Comment: You can't, of course, and you certainly can't assume it is <= the old object. Use a buffer large enough for any object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the packet sent from the server is larger than the original one, therefore, on the client, we must receive data into the buffer with a margin, and from there try to read the data.

This is an edited Client code:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
ds.receive(dp);
```